# Show a ProgressDialog and send an SMS in the background

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I have written a procedure that

1. shows a `ProgressDialog`
2. sends an SMS
3. updates the View from another thread
4. hides the `ProgressDialog`

But it seems to me that this is not the best way to do this. I would like to hear advice and my mistakes. It seems to me that it is possible to optimize the code for quick work procedures.

```
public boolean sendCommand(commandXDev command, final String uniValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("serjaru.bsh.xdev2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String phoneNumber = prefs.getString("phonenumber", "");
    int gateway = prefs.getInt("gateway", 0);

    if (gateway == 0) {


        if (command == commandXDev.Get) {
            final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(Relays.this, "Please wait", "Sending SMS...", true);
            progress.setCancelable(true);


            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if (myPhone.sendSMSMessage("+" + phoneNumber, ImeiPhone + "#get")) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                statusLabel.setText("SMS sended!");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                statusLabel.setText("Error. SMS not sended.");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is such a common pattern (run some command in separate thread and then modify the UI with the result) that Android has a class just for that: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  There is also a small [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) in the dev guide and I'm sure all Android books must have a full section, if not a full chapter, about AsyncTask.

Be very careful about Java conventions.  When you don't respect them, the code is quite confusing for Java developers.

- Class names always start a capital letter, so `CommandXDev` instead of `commandXDev`.
- `commandXDev.Get`.  I'm not quite sure what that is.  In Java, if you write a getter method, you always call it `get` followed by what you are getting, i.e. `getName()`, `getId()`, `getSharedPreferences()`, etc.  Your `commandXDev.Get` seems to be a static getter, which is best avoided.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  Maybe look into the singleton pattern.

Minor point: in English it is "sent" instead of "sended".  It does not make sense, but it is how it is.